# Remove extra backslash from only one json key value pair in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here is the small portion JSON generating from mysql table .

```
{
  "id":"2",
  "project_title":"Jade Heights Tower II",
  "project_description":"\\u2022first one\\n\\u2022second one edited\\n",
  "latitude":"10.019615",
  "longitude":"76.339418",
  "property_type":" Luxury Apartments",
  "property_city":" Kakkanad",
  "property_status":"to-sell",
  "image_url":"http:\/\/zama.in\/miradmin\/assets\/images\/5d568e8ad9.jpg"
}
```

In this i want to remove the extra backslashes only from the `project_description`
 tag.

**Current**

```
"project_description":"\\u2022first one\\n\\u2022second one edited\\n"
```

**Expected:**

`"project_description":"\u2022first one\n\u2022second one edited\n`"

Here is tried code.

```
$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mir_projects` ORDER BY `id`");
    $result->execute();
    if($result->rowCount()){

        $output = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: i need to display this in androd textview  `\u2022` and `\n` are used to generate bulletpoints and newline characters in the textview.

Comment: The backslash is escaping your other backslash. When decoding the JSON you'll see your original data.

Comment: Them you should remove extra slashes in your android app.

Comment: How can i remove it from android?.

Comment: @daan its still showing two slashes in android textview

Comment: @BlessanKurien Then you aren't decoding it well.

Comment: Please wait i will update my android decoding code here.

Comment: Try `project_description.replace("\\u2022", "\u2022")` and `project_description.replace("\\n", "\n")`. But actually, looks like your "project_description" string is json-encoded too. So you should decode it separately after decoding the whole json object.

Comment: @ksimka let me try that.

Answer (score 2):

first, decode the json using json_decode($str,true) and then

try this,

```
<?php
$str="\\u2022first one\\n\\u2022second one edited\\n";
$newdescription = preg_replace('/\+/', "/\/", $str);
print_r($newdescription);
?>
```